# Async componentDidMout and forceUpdate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

I can't understand, why in the attached code example `async componentDidMount` method runs `forceUpdate` not immediately but waiting `funcLazyLoad` promise to be resolved. I expect that `forceUpdate` will be waiting for promise resolving only in such construction `await funcLazyLoad(1000).then(this.forceUpdate)`

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

let data = ''

async function funcLazyLoad(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(ms)
    }, ms)
  })
}

class App extends React.Component {
  async componentDidMount() {
    data = await funcLazyLoad(1000)
    this.forceUpdate()
  }

  render() {
    console.log('Render')
    return <div>Hello {data}</div>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/practical-aryabhata-vg3h64?file=%2Fsrc%2Findex.js%3A15%2C30  .

Comment: What do you think the `await` does in `componentDidMount`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, the **componentDidMount** method is marked as **async**, and it contains an **await** statement for **funcLazyLoad(1000)**.

The await keyword pauses the execution of the componentDidMount method until the promise returned by funcLazyLoad(1000) is resolved.

However, since **funcLazyLoad** returns a Promise that resolves after a timeout of 1000 milliseconds, the rest of the **componentDidMount** method (specifically, the **this.forceUpdate()** part) will only be executed after the promise is resolved.

So, the sequence of events is as follows:

1. **componentDidMount** is called.
2. **funcLazyLoad(1000)** is invoked, and the method pauses until the promise is resolved.
3. After a delay of 1000 milliseconds, the promise is resolved, and the data variable is updated.
4. **this.forceUpdate()** is executed, triggering a re-render of the component.

If you want to wait for the promise to resolve before calling **forceUpdate**, your current implementation is correct. If you want to wait for the promise to resolve within the render method before rendering the updated data, you would need to use setState instead of **forceUpdate**, as **setState** triggers a re-render upon completion:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  async componentDidMount() {
    data = await funcLazyLoad(1000);
    this.setState({}); // This will trigger a re-render when the promise is resolved.
  }

  render() {
    console.log('Render');
    return <div>Hello {data}</div>;
  }
}
```

This way, the render method will be called after the promise is resolved, ensuring that the updated data is displayed.

Comment: "*you would need to use setState instead of forceUpdate, as setState triggers a re-render upon completion*" - but so does `forceUpdate`?

Comment: @Bergi Both setState and forceUpdate allow you to update the state of a component, triggering a re-render. However, they have some differences in how they operate. 

setState is the primary recommended to modify state as it ensures the correct asynchronous state updates and triggers a re-render.

On the other hand, forceUpdate is a less common method and is typically used when a component's state is not directly modified. Still, its internal state depends on some external data. It is not considered a best practice and should be used sparingly.

Answer (score 0):

As JavaScript works like an interpreter,the function componentDidMount() waits for the funcLazyLoad(1000) to run, later it runs the forceUpdate().I hope this helps with your issue.